# Freeing up space in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, space

I wonder if anyone can point me in the right direction with this please.

I have a number of tables in a SQL Server database and I have used a script to analyze the space that's being used by each table.

The script can be found here if anyone's interested: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=61762

My table sizes only account for about a third of the size of the database, so my question is what is using the rest of space and how can I reduce the overall database size?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to reclaim space because you have disk space problems? If not, leave it.

You are almost certain to cause issues by shrinking database and/or files:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/06/13/629059.aspx
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff808322.aspx
- http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Why-you-should-not-shrink-your-data-files.aspx
- http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/A-SQL-Server-DBA-myth-a-day-%28930%29-data-file-shrink-does-not-affect-performance.aspx

Quoting from the last one:

```
Myth #9: Data file shrink does not affect performance.

Hahahahahahahahahahahahahahaha! <snort>

<wipes tears from eyes, attempts to focus on laptop screen, cleans drool from keyboard>
```

Generally the database needs to be this size if it *is* this size based on previous auotgrows.

For example, you need free space of approximately 1.2 times your biggest table when indexes are being rebuilt. If one table is 25% of your data then this table consumes 55% during index rebuilds.

So, *don't* do it unless you have a severe need...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this is SQL Server specific,

DBCC SHRINKDATABASE

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258287%28v=sql.80%29.aspx